# Assembly problems with ML ONNX Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, fileloadexception, onnxruntime

I always get the following exception:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: "Die Datei oder Assembly "Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime, Version=0.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f27f157f0a5b7bb6" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Die gefundene Manifestdefinition der Assembly stimmt nicht mit dem Assemblyverweis überein.

The assembly seems not to be found. In my Csproj file the hintpath links to the correct nuget paket. I don't know what else I can try. First I had the same problem with System.Memory 4.0.1.0 and now this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I have solved the problem with the Hint-Path of the .csproj file